# Issue Updating Adobe Analytics Variable Via Data Element in Dynamic Tag Manager - DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have Adobe Analytics set-up as a tool in DTM. I have a "Page Name" data element which references a JS Object ( digitalData.page.pageInfo.pageID). In the tool set-up area, Global Variables, I have prop1 set to %Hostname%:%Page Name%. I also have under Pageviews and Content, Page Name set to  %Hostname%:%Page Name%. Issue is at the point DTM sets the values here, it doesn't have access to the digitalData object (timing issue I'm trying to resolve below).

I have I had an issue with the object not being available when the DTM code was running so I put in a page load rule to suppress the Analytics call

`s.abort = true;`

and then in the 3rd party JavaScript area I put in code to check for the object to be detected and I get the expected value in my console output.

`(function() { 
    try {
        function checkObj(){
            if (digitalData === null || digitalData  === undefined) {
                setTimeout(checkObj(), 200); 
            }else{
                var pn = _satellite.getVar("Page Name");
                console.log("----> object available - Page Name DE holds:" + pn);
                _satellite.track("Analytics Call");
                return;
            }
        }
        checkObj();
    } catch(e) {e.message(e);}
})();`

In the Direct Call Rule, "Analytics Call", I set the Adobe Page Name and prop1 again to %Hostname%:%Page Name% but the page name is still blank (only host name is output with colon) when the Analytics Call goes out?

In testing, I noticed in the Analytics Tool set-up, in the Pageviews and Content section, if I remove the values from the Page Name setting text box then nothing is output for pageName when the analytics call goes out?

So my issue is how do I get the Page Name and prop1 variables to update with the   new value of the digitalData object when the analytics call goes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this seems to be a race condition between when your DL object is available and when the page load rule executes, I would do the following:

- Create a "global page load rule" for this use case instead of using the AA global configuration section within the tool.
- Within the AA custom code section of the global page load rule set s.abort = true. This will allow you to wait for all of your other objects to load.
- Call a direct call rule when all objects are loaded
- Within the DC rule check for your DL object (pageName) and set AA vars.

Example code in DC rule

```
   if(Data_Layer_Obj)
   s.pageName = datalayer.pageName
}
```

Waiting for a Data Element here may be a challenge because of the timing issues between the page load rule and your data layer objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark,Thanks for the reply. So are you saying remove Adobe Analytics as a tool and manually load it via a page load rule?

Comment: No. Leave the AA tool as is and execute your code within a page load rule with no conditions. This will fire it on all pages. You can then set s.abort = true within the AA custom code (within the rule) and then call your DC rule.

Comment: Hi Mark, that is exactly what I'm doing. The good news is I just had the JS object I'm sourcing, moved up the page (as far as load order) and that solved my issue. The thing that throws me is that I though if I updated the source the "Page Name" data element was sourcing and called _satellite.getVar("Page Name").. then the next time the Page Name data element was called by analytics (%Page Name%) that s.pageName would be updated but that doesn't seem the case?

Comment: Because this is a tricky case I would assign / set your AA vars within the DC rule directly. That way you always know that the data exists and can forget about any sequential page load dependencies.